# Turn number in exponential form to decimal

Tags: c#, double, decimal, exponential

I am trying to convert a number in exponential form to its decimal equivalent. For example:

`3e43 => 3 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 0`

I've read the docs and it says that I may do this with 
`double.Parse(expNumber.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);`

But when I try to convert 3e43 to decimal it just converts it to 3E+43 and not to the number I am expecting (I know it's about the double datatype precision). Is there a way to do that?

Also, is there any way to convert 3e-43 to its decimal equivalent? It seems that decimal.toString doesn't work this time as it is such an small number.

Comment: I just noticed that I can dinamically change the number of decimals I want to show even if its decimal or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see all the zeros

just use [`Double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) it has various overloads to do different things

```
var input = "3e43";
var val = double.Parse(input, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
Console.WriteLine(val);
Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("N0"));
Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("f"));
```

**Output**

```
3E+43
30,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
```

[**Full demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ivcPFf)

---

**Additional resouces**

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: It wors like a charm with positive numbers!! Does it work with decimals like 3e-43 instead of 3e43?